# How to get items from feed in iphone?

Tags: iphone

iam developing RSS Reader, i need to get the items from the given Feed URL.I used Touch XML for this, but this is very slow.Is there any faster way? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NSXMLParser is the raw XML parser